# Using Refit hyperparameter when using RandomizedSeachCV from sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I am running a random forest classifier model. After hypertuning the parameters, the precision for my negative class is only coming in at 0.51. So in order to improve my precision score, I am passing scoring = precision_score and refit = 'precision' in my randomized search CV algorithm. However, when I check the best estimator, it is showing the exact same estimator as before. Can someone explain why this may be happening?

Here is a snippet of the code I am using:

```
#Use precision

scorers = {'precision': make_scorer(precision_score)}

#Initialize RandomizedSearchCv

rfc_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = rfc, cv = 5, param_distributions=params_rfc, random_state=42, refit = 'precision', scoring= scorers)
```

Comment: check the `cv_results_`; maybe 0.51 is actually the best. Note however that `precision_score` gives the precision of the _positive_ class.

Comment: @BenReiniger do you know what I should use to get the precision of the negative class?

Comment: `precision_score` has a parameter `pos_label` for that, and you can use the kwargs of `make_scorer` to pass that option into the scorer.